# SolrCloud SQL cast exception

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a collection with several fields with different types and when I run a SQL query only works with the string type fields. If I try to select a *int/long/float/double* field, I got a exception similar to this one.

```
"result-set":{
    "docs":[{
        "EXCEPTION":"java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String",
        "EOF":true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME":276}]}}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

I am using **Solr 6.6**. Fields type definitions are below.

```
<fieldType name="StrField" class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField"/>
<fieldType name="TextField" class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField">
<fieldType name="TrieDoubleField" class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDoubleField"/>
  <fieldType name="TrieFloatField" class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieFloatField"/>
  <fieldType name="TrieIntField" class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieIntField"/>
  <fieldType name="TrieLongField" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>
```

All SQL queries with a list of columns as StrField and TextField do work.

I've tried out with **Solrj** driver with the same luck for the all the number types defined above. Strings/Texts work ok.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: java.io.IOException: --> http://xx.xx.xx.xx:7574/solr/collection_test_shard2_replica2/:java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.StatementImpl.executeQueryImpl(StatementImpl.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:111)
    at tng.Sql.run(Sql.java:40)
    at tng.MainSolrCloud.main(MainSolrCloud.java:52)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.io.IOException: --> http://xx.xx.xx.xx:7574/solr/collection_test_shard2_replica2/:java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.ResultSetImpl.<init>(ResultSetImpl.java:83)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.StatementImpl.executeQueryImpl(StatementImpl.java:71)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: --> http://x.xx.x.xx:7574/solr/collection_test_shard2_replica2/:java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.SolrStream.read(SolrStream.java:233)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.PushBackStream.read(PushBackStream.java:87)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.sql.ResultSetImpl.<init>(ResultSetImpl.java:80)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: I am not using Solrj yet. Just went through the web interface. Just adding the stmt=select id,run from test_collection where run=1000815. All using the /sql endpoint

Comment: could you show your sql http request then?

Comment: http://alioth:8983/solr/test_collection/sql?indent=on&q=*:*&stmt=select%20id,run%20from%20test_collection%20where%20run=1000815%20limit%201&wt=json

Comment: This is how i defined the field in schema.xml <fieldType name="TrieLongField" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" docValues="true" precisionStep="0"/>

Comment: please add it to question itself, it will be easy to overlook it in comments later

Comment: also, please add info about fieldType and field itself in the question body. ty

Comment: From a fresh Solr 6.6.1 install, I still got the same issue.

Comment: Same issue using JDBC client and Solr 6.6.1